# Multiple attribute for input tag in html 5 doesnt allow user to upload multiple images in android devices

Tags: html, forms

Input tag with multiple attribute fails to accept multiple images for android devices.

I tested it over Android 4.4 for Samsung, HTC, Sony using google chrome and default browser.

But it works perfectly fine for iOS devices using Google chrome and default browser.

Can somebody tell me what is missing?

Comment: <input type="file" class= "form-control" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/>  The line of code that I am using for multiple image uploads..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code in your question is the code you use, I got a very easy answer for you. After your second attribute (your class), there is a space between '=' and '"'. Because of that space, it won't go any further than the first attribute. I think iOS fixes this automatically and Android doesn't.The correct code should be:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @joshua but it still takes one image for android device..I tested using HTC with OS 4.4...Thanks for the help though